# How to deal with additional methods in MVC design pattern

Tags: java, laravel, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

When we develop using MVC pattern it happens to need to having additional methods that could achieve basic operations on our models.

An example is an *agregate getter* that return the total count of the user records on the persistence base.

```
int getUsersCount();
```

Where is the best place to put such of those methods? In the model? In the controller?

Is there any difference between specific SDK/languages?

- Java EE
- Android
- Laravel
- vanilla PHP
- ...

Thanks.

Comment: Wherever you'd put any function that will execute queries on the underlying database. The model mostly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this article that discuss about it: [here it is a overview comparison between Purist OOP and Anemic Domain Model](http://blog.ccoder.co.uk/) .

The overview basically explains that there are two big difference in the way you can implement a MVC design pattern.

The first way is about concetrate the methods, like the aggregate getter in this case, in a model related controller class.

For example, in Android, when we persist models in local or remote database, or we have to serialize it, or to marshall it, we tend to create those kind of ModelController classes and have so an **anemic** MVC pattern with clean POJO models.

```
class User extends MySuperModel{
    int id;
    String username;
    //getters and setters
}

class UserController{
    User getUserById(int id);
    int getUsersCount();
}
```

The other way, consists in concentrate all the methods in the model class itself, for example as in Laravel (where controllers are demand to mainly control the post-routing and pre-rendering of a view, but doesn't tends to have other methods and neither their easy to instantiate. In this case we have a **controlled domain** MVC, and the additional model related methods should be in the model class itself.

```
class User extends Eloquent\Model{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'username']
    function getUserById($id);
    function getUsersCount();
}
```